# Libreoffice Calc Tokenize (?) a Cell

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Hello and thanks in advance for answers.

I have a spreadsheet in Calc that contains a cell that contains minutes played for goalies. An example of data in the cell is:

1975:30:00

This means 1975 minutes and 30 seconds.

I'm trying to "tokenize" (I don't know if that is proper term) by the : and present the data in 3 adjacent cells.

For example:

A1: 1975:30:30
A2: 1975
A3: 30
A4: 00

I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I'm quite proficient in Excel but I don't want to pay for another licence on the laptop I'm using for this project so I'm using LibreOffice Calc. I am beginner level in LibreOffice Calc.

So please keep in mind my newbie status in Calc if you are able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

A1: 1975:30:00

A2: =Quotient(A1 * 24, 1)

A3: =Mod(A1 * 24, 1) * 60

A4: is not needed.